# Import csv file and send to backend

Tags: csv, redux, frontend, backend, nestjs

I try to create a redux-react app where the users can import an csv-file that later is stored in a database. Right now I am working on the frontend where I want to create a code where the user can chose a csv file from their computer that they want to download and then the file is sent to the backend. I have therfore used the csvReader to read the csv-file but **I don't know how to send the data to the backend**. I am using nestJS in the backend. I want to send the whole csv-file in one go but i dont know how to tackle the problem. I am a beginner :))) Do you know how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't help you with react but maybe this NestJS part can help you. You can use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) to config your api and setting a store path.

1. Create multer options

   ```
   // multer.ts

   const excelMimeTypes = [
      'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
      'application/wps-office.xlsx',
      'application/vnd.ms-excel',
   ];

   export const multerOptions = {
      fileFilter: (req: any, file: any, cb: any) => {
         const mimeType = excelMimeTypes.find(im => im === file.mimetype);

          if (mimeType) {
             cb(null, true);
          } else {
             cb(new HttpException(`Unsupported file type ${extname(file.originalname)}`, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST), false);
       }
   },
   storage: diskStorage({
       destination: (req: any, file: any, cb: any) => {
           const uploadPath = '/upload'; // use env var
           if (!existsSync(uploadPath)) {
               mkdirSync(uploadPath);   // create if not exists
           }
           cb(null, uploadPath);
       },
       filename: (req: any, file: any, cb: any) => {
           cb(null, file.originalname);
       },
    }),
   };
   ```
2. Import multerOption recent created and use FileInterceptor and UploadedFile decorator to get the file.

   ```
   @Post()
   @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file', multerOptions))
   uploadFile(@UploadedFile() file) {
       console.log(file) // call service or whathever to manage uploaded file.. handleFile in the example below..
   }
   ```
3. Manage file (example) using [xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) library.

   ```
   handleFile(file: any): Promise<any> {
       return new Promise(async (resolve: (result: any) => void, reject: (reason: any) => void): Promise<void> => {
           try {
               const workbook = XLSX.readFile(`${uploadLocation}/${file.filename}`);
               resolve(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
           } catch (error) {
               reject(error);
           }
       });
   }
   ```

I hope it helps!